# bootstrap filterable popover disappear in mobile when table is responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I already search but I don't found a solution anywhere...

I have a table-responsive and I want to filter by column (img 1).
My filter is based on [this filter](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Pretty-Table-Filter-Plugin-With-jQuery-Bootstrap-Filterable/) and i have a problem. When I saw the table in my mobile phone the editable popover not appear (img 2) because the filter is within the table.

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

[EDIT] Someone tried responsive tables with popovers inside them in mobile?!

[EDIT] The example is to long to put here, but you can view [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/PfHab/10/)
with table-responsive in div class  ex: `<div class="table-responsive"> <table> ... </table> </div>`.

Anyone can help me? 
If you need more information please tell me please.

Thanks

Comment: any code would be helpful

Comment: another example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6jd2U/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two weeks of research and trying everything I know finally I solve the problem.

In my case I added the default values ​​of the **popover** an option in the script line 1392
**bootstrap-editable.js**

line   code

```
1   / *! X-editable - v1.5.1
.
...
1390 mode: 'popup',
1391
1392 container: 'body'
```

So the popover is no longer "inside the table" and now belongs to the **body**, therefore, is in front of the other objects..

My reference: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover_plugin.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have to edit the JS file but defined `container` as `'body'` in `popover` initiation.